# Searching Facebook test users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Why when trying to use Graph API search method to look for a test user I always get empty list as a result?

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=ANOTHER_TEST_USER_NAME&type=user&access_token=ISSUED_BY_TEST_USER
```

Comment: My guess is that it isn't supported by Facebook yet